# Pass variable from one Javascript File to the another ( specific situation )

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have 2 different Javascript files.
How to i pass a Javascript variable inside a Jquery document function to another Javascript file.

chat.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var a = "something"
}
```

to scripts.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     console.log(a); //gives undefined
}
```

index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/chat.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/scripts.js"></script>
```

Notes: i am aware this theres a duplicate but not of this specific situation
I have tried multiple solutions such as globally declare the variable but wont work for me since this is for a socket.

Comment: Can you explain why you think globally declaring it won't work for you? Or show your attempt at doing so?

Comment: declare it with window.{{myVarName}}, then you can use it wherever you want.. P.S window is just so you can have better code style

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can use `localStorage`?

Try this:

Chat.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var a = "something";
   localStorage.setItem('a', a);
}
```

Scripts.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 console.log(localStorage.getItem('a'));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In chats.js:

```
var a;
$(document).ready(function () {
    a = "something"
}
```

In scripts.js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log(a); //gives something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either make a global(window) level variable and use it on both js file,
or make  global level function and pass the local variable as parameter to global function.